# Questions in proof of Fundamental theorem of algebra using Galois Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I am self studying Galois theory from  Hungerford. I have questions in the proof of Fundamental theorem of Algebra(Pg 266) and got struct on proof of Fundamental Theorem of Algebra.

Adding image ->[image]

> i have question in 2 line of 2 nd paragraph of proof . Please note that ||.5.7 is Sylow 1 st Theorem.

Kindly note that Result 3.18 there is no extension fields of dimension 2 over the field of complex numbers. ( In case it is used to deduce these). and (B) is every polynomial in $\mathbb{R}$[x] of odd degree has a root in $\mathbb{R} $

> Questions: 1.How does in 2nd line of 2nd paragraph $Aut_{R} F $ must have odd index whose fixed field has odd dimension?

and in last line of page 266 how does it implies degree must be 1?

> 

In last paragraph how does
Fundamental theorem of Galois Theory implies $E_0$
is an extension of $\mathbb{C} $ with dimension $[Aut_{C} F : J]=2$ ?

I know i have asked 3 questions but I am really struck on this and would be thankful for your help.

Comment: The index of a $p$-Sylow subgroup cannot be divisible by $p$, this follows from the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Sylow $p$-subgroup of a group $G$ has order $p^{n_p}$, where $p^{n_p}$ is the largest power of $p$ dividing $|G|$.  In your setting,
$$  |\mathrm{Aut}_{\Bbb{R}}\, F| = 2^n \cdot \text{[product of powers of odd primes]}  \text{,}  $$
so the index is a (possibly empty) product of powers of odd primes, so is odd.

As noted, the index of $E$ over $\Bbb{R}$ is the same as this index, so is odd.

This makes the minimal polynomial have odd degree.  Hypothesis (B) says this polynomial has a root in $\Bbb{R}$, so no extension (by $u$) is needed and the root is real, so its minimal polynomial (over $\Bbb{R}$) is linear.  (Every element of the base field is a root of a linear polynomial.  Let $u$ be such an element; $x - u$ is the polynomial.)

...

The previous paragraph ends with the assertion that $\mathrm{Aut}_{\Bbb{C}}\, F$ has order $2^m$, $0 \leq m$.  This paragraph starts by assuming $m > 0$.  There is a $2$-subgroup of order $2^{m-1}$ properly contained in a Sylow $2$-subgroup (of order $2^m$).  The Fundamental theorem show a correspondence between the degrees of the fields (also called the dimensions of the extensions) and the indices of the Galois groups.  So if the index of $J$ is $2$, the degree over the fixed field is also $2$.